# Can a non-quasi-static process have an equation of the path which it has followed?

Tags: thermodynamics

Recently I saw a question where there was a specific p-v relation for a process, but it was stated that it's not a quasi-static process. Hence, we can not calculate the work done by integration of pdv work.

Answer (score 1):

You can can calculate the work done by integrating $pdv$, but the pressure is the external pressure, not the gas pressure. For a non quasistatic process the gas is not in equilibrium internally as pressure gradients exist. That makes the internal pressure undefined.

This will respond to your follow up question:

***But, how can it have a function of its path?***

For a non quasi-static process the function only represents the external applied pressure and the volume of the gas. All other properties of the gas are undefined during the process because the gas is not in internal equilibrium. Work is always $pdv$ where the pressure is the external pressure. Only if the process is carried out quasi statically is the internal gas pressure equal to the external pressure at each point of the process.

For example, for an ideal gas at equilibrium we have $PV=nRT$. Since the gas is not in internal equilibrium during a non quasi-static process, this equation does not apply at each point of the process with the exception that $V$ in the function does represent the volume of the gas but temperature and pressure are not in internal equilibrium. In other words, the points on the process curve only represent equilibrium states of the gas if the process is carried out quasi statically. You can apply the ideal gas equation at the initial equilibrium state before the process starts and at the final state when the process stops and the gas is allowed to reach internal equilibrium, but not at the points in between.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But, how can it have a function of its path?

Comment: @ChodagangaPradhan I have revised my answer to respond to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. I got it now.

Comment: @ChodagangaPradhan Sorry, I thought it was you who asked this follow up question

Comment: I only asked the question. Just now I changed my profile name. I am Chodaganga Pradhan.

Comment: @Hitish_cp OK, that clears that up. So then do you find my answer acceptable?